# Не загружается карта MapView

Tags: android

Вот мой код. проверяю на Андроид 4.0.4 (гугл карта обновлена до последней версии)

```
 public class waw extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        private final String LOG_TAG = "tx";
        private MyApplication singleton;
        private MapView mapView;
        private GoogleMap gMap;
        private Location fromLocation = null;
        private Location toLocation = null;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onAttach");

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onCreate");


    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onCreateView");

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qwed, null);
        singleton = MyApplication.getInstance(); 

        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return v;
    }




    ///.....
///.....

 /* maps code Override*/
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        gMap = map;
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                LatLng(54.888200, 52.270557), 20));
    }
/* maps code Override*/








}
```

[image: Окно с картой (снизу видно что Google (c) загрузился)]

Comment: это происходит когда запускаешь установленный `apk` или `debug`-версию ?

Comment: debug версию, api ключ тоже дебаг версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавить библиотеку `google play services` в проект.
   В `build-grandle` добавить:
   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.x.x'` - версия `play services`
2. В манифесте:

`<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="AIzaSyComUhEqr9BL4JjqJE05Lck4j1uABIU08Y">
    </meta-data>`


    `<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
    </meta-data>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"></uses-permission>`

Гугл-карты используют `OpenGL ES` версии 2. На девайсах, которые это не поддерживают, карта просто не отобразится. Поэтому:

`<uses-feature
 android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
 android:required="true">
</uses-feature>`

Comment: спасибо,   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
Сама карта от гугла работает нормально, Приложение "Карты" как я понимаю там тоже используется v2 ? и следовательно если мой планшет поддерживает работу стандартной карты то и MapView должен работать нормально?

Comment: @DuosDuo, да, все должно работать